# Delegate reference disappears on modal Popup

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates, xib

This is convoluted, so I will do my best to give as much info as possible. My main UIViewController opens a modal popup in the form of an Info screen.

here is the call from MainViewController

```
infoPopup = [ModalPopup modalPopupWithDelegate:self];

[infoPopup presentInView:self.view.window];

[self.view addSubview:infoPopup];
```

and here is the receiving method in ModalPopup

```
+ (id)modalPopupWithDelegate:(id <ModalPopupDelegate>)dlg {

ModalPopup *info = [[ModalPopup alloc] init];
info.delegate = dlg;

return info;
}
```

In ModalPopup I create a protocol with an optional method of "modalPopupFinished" and make MainViewController the delegate.

in ModalPopup I've add a UIScrollView and insert 5 UIViews into the scrollview.

I created the views all in the same XIB file

```
NSString *infoXib;

if (IS_IPAD)
    infoXib = @"info_iPad";
else
    infoXib = @"info_iPhone";

NSArray *views;

views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:infoXib owner:self options:nil];
UIView *v1 = [views objectAtIndex:0];

views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:infoXib owner:self options:nil];
UIView *v2 = [views objectAtIndex:1];

views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:infoXib owner:self options:nil];
UIView *v3 = [views objectAtIndex:2];

views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:infoXib owner:self options:nil];
UIView *v4 = [views objectAtIndex:3];

views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:infoXib owner:self options:nil];
UIView *v5 = [views objectAtIndex:4];

NSArray *pages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, nil];
[self setPagesInArray:pages];


- (void)setPagesInArray:(NSArray *)pages {

    if (pages) {

        int numberOfPages = pages.count;

        [pageScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(pageScroll.frame.size.width * numberOfPages, pageHeight)];
        pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;

        NSUInteger i = 0;

        while (i < numberOfPages) {

            UIView *page = [pages objectAtIndex:i];
            page.frame = CGRectMake(pageWidth * i, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
            [pageScroll addSubview:page];

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

the Views load fine in the scrollview and I can scroll through them all as expected.

One of the views in the XIB as some buttons and I've made the view a member of the Custom Class ModalPopup. I've wired the buttons to some IBActions in ModalPopup, and they fire as expected.

In ModalPopup I create a close button that fires the delegates "modalPopupFinished" event on MainViewController.

```
- (void)finishCloseAnimation {

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(modalPopupFinished)])
        [_delegate modalPopupFinished];

    [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

No Problems everything works great...except

when I press one of the buttons from the View and goto fire a delegate method, it has lost its brain and can't remember the delegate

```
- (IBAction)facebook:(id)sender {

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sendLikeFacebook)])
        [_delegate sendLikeFacebook];
}
```

In fact when I get into the Facebook method on ModalPopup everything is nil.

The method that I am trying to fire in MainViewController opens

```
[self presentViewController:composeController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

thus I want to open it from the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have 2 instances of ModalPopup.  Since you say that you wired your buttons to ModalPopup in IB, this leads me to believe you are creating an instance of ModalPopup in the xib which is distinct from the ModalPopup that you have created programmatically.  The fact that the ModalPopup that is called when the button is pressed is "completely empty" is further evidence.

If this is the case, instead of programmatically creating the ModalPopup, you should get the instance from the xib, just like you get the views.  I would also suspect that you already added the views to the ModalPopup in the xib which means you do not have to manually add them as well.

Comment: You nailed it Peter, There was 2 instances. As soon as I changed the custom class on the view with the buttons in XIB from ModalPopup to just UIView and rewired them it all worked.